# Obtener los registros mas bajos de una columna (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo los siguientes datos de estatura de personas :

```
LORENA GARCIA',1.58
LORENA RAMOS',1.68
JAIME SALAS',1.68
GABRIEL OBREGON',1.82
AUGUSTO ZAMORA',1.80
MARIO UGALDE',1.80
LETICIA CASTILLO',1.58
SELENE MARES',1.7
```

Quisiera saber un select para tomar los datos mas bajos de la columna 'estatura' eh usado el select min(estatura) pero solo me da una de las dos personas que tienen la estatura mas baja (1.58)(Leticia y Lorena)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA ORDER BY ESTARURA DESC;
```

Gracias.

Comment: Podrias mostrar lo que has intentado poniendo el codigo sql que usaste, creo que el problema se resuelve usando un GROUP BY pero habria que ver el codigo para saber como usarlo saludos

Comment: Eh usado la siguiente consulta: SELECT  min(estatura) FROM personas limit 2; pero solo me muestra uno de los dos que deberia mostrar

Comment: A que te refieres con los mas bajos los quieres todos o solo los mas bajos?
Quisieras recuperar a Lorena y Leticia solamente?

Comment: Seleccionar el o los mas bajos osea ahorita son leticia y lorena pero si se agrega otro de 1.58 que se muestre tambien

Comment: Prueba con ese codigo que te puse debe de funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no estoy mal debe ser algo como esto claro ya con tu tabla yo usare Estaturas como nombre de la tabla y Estatura como campo.

```
SELECT Nombre,Estatura AS Menor 
FROM  Estaturas 
where Estatura = ( SELECT MIN(Estatura)FROM  Estaturas  )
```

Lo que hacemos es Recuperar el nombre y la estatura pero el truco esta en aplicar el WHERE donde se encuentre el minino en este caso el 1.58 entonces nos devuelve los registros que cumplan con esta condición

Comment: Funciono!!! Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Qué código utilizaste? cual es el nombre de las columnas?
se me ocurre algo como esto`SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TABLA ORDER BY ESTATURA DESC;`

Comment: Hola, en esa consulta me aparecen todos los datos y quisiera unicamente el/los mas bajos

Comment: Te dejo este enlace para que te perfecciones un poco en eso a mí me fué muy util cuando estaba aprendiendo [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: Dame un numero exacto, si solo 5 o 4 o 3, me explico?

Comment: Hola creo que solo necesitas añadir un top al select ya he mofidicado el comentario revisa esa consulta por favor.`SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TABLA ORDER BY ESTATURA DESC`; solo cambia el numero 5 por la cantidad que desees.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Puedes intentar ejecutar la siguiente sentencia (Aclaro que le cambié el nombre de la columna a "estatura" en lugar de "ESTARURA")

`SELECT * FROM prueba ORDER BY estatura ASC LIMIT 2;`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`SELECT * FROM prueba ORDER BY estatura ASC LIMIT 5;`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]